# regex decompiler

Tags: regex, perl

I found this regex and want to understand it. Are there any regex decompilers that will translate what the following regex does into words? It is really complicated.

```
$text =~ /(((\w)\W*(?{$^R.(0+( q{a}lt$3))})) {8}(?{print +pack"B8" ,$^Rand ""})) +/x;
```

Comment: You should cite the source :) http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=530128

Comment: heh, i found it in at this http://cs.usu.edu.ru/langs/perl/obfuperl.htm russian site. but you're right. Will cite.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Using `YAPE::Regex::Explain`](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm) (not sure if it is good, but it's the first result in searching):

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
my $REx = qr/(((\w)\W*(?{$^R.(0+( q{a}lt$3))})) {8}(?{print +pack"B8" ,$^Rand ""})) +/x;
my $exp = YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($REx)->explain;
print $exp;
```

I've got the explanation as:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2 (8 times):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \W*                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z,
                               0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?{$^R.(0+(              run this block of Perl code
      q{a}lt$3))})
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){8}                     end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                             quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?{print +pack"B8"       run this block of Perl code
    ,$^Rand ""})
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
```

There are 2 blocks of Perl code, which must be analyzed independently.

In the first block:

```
$^R . (0 + (q{a} lt $3))
```

here, [`$^R` is](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LAST_REGEXP_CODE_RESULT) "the result of evaluation of the last successful `(?{ code })` regular expression assertion", and the expression `(0 + (q{a} lt $3))` gives 1 if the 3rd capture is in `[b-z]`, 0 otherwise.

In the second block:

```
print +pack "B8", $^R and ""
```

it interpret the previous result of evaluation as a [(big-endian) binary string, get the number, convert it to the corresponding character](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), and finally print it out.

---

Together, the regex finds every 8 alphanumeric characters, then treat those in `[b-z]` as the binary digit 1, otherwise 0. These 8 binary digits are then interpreted as a character code, and that character is printed out.

For instance, the letter 'H' = 0b01001000 would be printed when matching the string

```
$test = 'OvERfLOW';
```

Comment: Why did you leave off the first 13 lines of the explanation?

Comment: @daxim: Because those are not important (plus the `(?x-ims:...)` part doesn't really exist in the regex anyway (it is transformed from the flag `/x`).)

Comment: Thank you really very much for the explanation. I has no chance understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what all is in that statement, but for regex analyzing i use this site

http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html

Comment: Cannot deal with the regex from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I always found [OptiPerl's](http://www.xarka.com/optiperl/) Regex Editor to be really good at this type of thing